# How get a input value and send him to another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an modal component, and inside this i have two input how i can get the value inserted in this input and send him to another component?

```js
  <template>
    <modal v-if="Modal">
      div(class="modal-title has-text-centered" slot="header")
      div(slot="content")
        div(class="control")
          div(class="columns")
            div(class="column")
              div(class="field")
                div(class="control")
                  input(class="input is-info is-large" type="text" placeholder="Analysis name")
              div(class="field")
                div(class="control")
                  input(class="input is-info is-large" type="text" placeholder="Item name")
       
        div(slot="footer")
          button(class="button is-info is-large modal-button" @click="closeModal"  style="margin-right:5em;") Cancel
          <router-link :to="{name: 'analyse'}" class="button is-info is-large modal-button">Create</router-link>
    </modal> 
</template>
<script>
import JwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'
import Modal from '../layout/modal/Basemodal.vue'
import Section from '../../views/Section.vue'
export default {
  data: function() {
    return { 
      user: '',
      isActive: false, 
      isDrop: false,
      Modal: false,
      analyseName: '',
      analyseItem: '',
      application: '',
    }
  },
  components: {
    'modal': Modal,
    'section-content': Section,
  },
  methods: {
    // on-click logout the user and send him to the initial page
    logout: function(){
      this.$store.dispatch('logout')
      .then(resp => {
        this.$router.push('/')
      })
    },
    // used to change the color of the selected button
    toggle: function(event) {
      event.ldaModal = !event.ldaModal
    },
    createAnalyse: function() {
      this.$route.push('/analyse')
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // render user token to get all user information
    this.user = JwtDecode(localStorage.getItem('token'))
  }
}
</script>
```

and here i have another component, in this component i need to get the value of modal and render it

```js
<template lang="pug">
  p {{ input1-value }}
  p {{ input2-value }}
</template>
```

please, what's the best approach to do this?

Comment: Since you are already using a store, why not add the value to the store and pick it up from the other component?

Comment: How can I do something like you said?, my skills in vuejs is supra noob ><

thanks for your answer

Comment: You'd have to show the code for your store, so we can suggest how can you adapt it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use the EventBus to solve your question.

in main.js

```
const bus = new Vue()
Vue.prototype.$bus = bus
```

you can register an event listener

```
this.$bus.on( 'test', ( data ) => {
 console.log( 'test', data );
} );
```

and emit it

```
this.$bus.emit( 'test', { code: 1 } );
```

you also can look at https://github.com/yyued/hub.js